# AngularJS: re-apply formatter after parser has executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've written a custom directive in an AngularJS app that I apply to a text input. The directive defines a `parser` to convert the user input to a number. At the same time, the directive also defines a `formatter` that interprets the number from the model and converts it back to text input for display. It looks something like this:

```
qvangular.directive('mydirective', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(v) {
                return convertToNumber(v);
            });
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(v) {
                return formatNumber(v);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

It kinda works, but the problem I have is this: with this approach the formatter only runs when the data model is initially bound (or when its value changes in code), but it does not run when the model is changed from the user input. I would like the formatter to run after the user has changed the input (and the input has been interpreted by the parser and applied to the model). Is there a way to do it?

EDIT: a practical example, in case the questione wasn't clear:

1. The user types "1K" in the text box
2. When the text box loses focus, the parser function runs and calls `convertToNumber("1K")`, which converts the string to the number `1000` and returns it
3. The value `1000` is applied to the model
4. **Now I would like the formatter function to run**, so it can read the value `1000` and convert it to what I want to display, for example `"1,000.00"`

**Step 4 is what is missing**, I don't know how to force AngularJS to "re-evaluate the model" and thus re-apply the formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my input masks, I actually re-render the model's view value in the parser:

```
ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(v) {
  ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(formatNumber(v));
  ngModelCtrl.$render();
  return convertToNumber(v);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a less "hacky" solution

Answer (score 1):

One common solution would be to bind `blur` event and format the value there:

```
element.bind('blur', () => {
     let value = element.val();
     let formatted = formatNumber(value);    
     element.val(formatted);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works though it feels a bit "hacky"... I'll accept your answer tomorrow if nobody comes up with something better